# Generics and Type inference

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have an abstract generic class `BLL<T> where T : BusinessObject`. I need to open an assembly that contains a set of concrete BLL classes, and return the tuples (businessObjectType, concreteBLLType) inside a Dictionary. There is the part of the method I could do until now, but I'm having problems to discover T.

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, Type> DefineBLLs()
{
   string bllsAssembly = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BLLsAssembly"];

   Type[] types = LoadAssembly(bllsAssembly);

   Dictionary<Type, Type> bllsTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

   foreach (Type type in types)
   {
     if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BLL<>)))
        /* how to know T in the situation below? */
        bllsTypes.Add(??businessObjectType (T)??, type);
   }

   return bllsTypes;
}
```

Comment: Well, what does T relate to here? It isn't clear (to me, at least) what the code is representing.

Comment: I think Jon probably cleared the code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the concrete classes will be closed rather than generic? Here's a short program which demonstrates what I *think* you're after...

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public abstract class Base<T>
{
}

public class Concrete : Base<string>
{
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Concrete);
        Type baseType = type.BaseType;
        Type typeOfT = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // Only one arg
        Console.WriteLine(typeOfT.Name); // Prints String
    }
}
```

Note that here I'm *assuming* that we only need to go up one level to get to the appropriate base type, and that the concrete class *will* be closed. You'd want to put more checks into your real code, of course, but I suspect it was the call to [GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) that you were missing.

Answer (score 0):

Jon, that is exactly what I was looking for. I use the basics of reflection and generics, so when it is needed a more profound knowledge of the API to confront both, I miss things like this one, thanks for answering.

Your assumptions are right, the concrete classes are closed, and T is defined on the base class (BLL).

The code became into this:

```
protected override Dictionary<Type, Type> DefineBLLs()
{
   string bllsAssembly = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BLLsAssembly"];

   Type[] types = LoadAssembly(bllsAssembly);

   Dictionary<Type, Type> bllsTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

   foreach (Type bllType in types)
   {
     if (bllType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BLL<>)))
     {
        Type baseType = bllType.BaseType;
        Type businessObjectType = baseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        bllsTypes.Add(businessObjectType, bllType);
     }
   }

   return bllsTypes;
}
```

Comment: I'd at least add a comment saying: "This will break if we have any deeper class hierarchies!" Just so you know what's wrong when it goes bang :)

Comment: Ok Jon, in my case BLL is at the same time the immediate base class from the concrete ones and BLL itself doesn't use inheritance ;)